# Postgres Text to json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column with the following text data (2 rows):

```
{"{john,m,25.01.1980}","{steve,m,12.12.1995}","{kate,f,17.04.1990}"}
{"{max,m,26.01.1980}","{sarah,f,18.04.1990}"}
```

This need to be converted into json like this (2 rows):

```
[{ "birth_date": 1234567890, "name": "john", "gender": "m" }, { "birth_date": 1234567890, "name": "steve", "gender": "m" }, { "birth_date": 1234567890, "name": "kate", "gender": "f" }]
[{ "birth_date": 1234567890, "name": "max", "gender": "m" }, { "birth_date": 1234567890, "name": "sarah", "gender": "f" }]
```

I have tried to use UNNEST, row_to_json and json_build_object, but cannot fugure out how to do this.

Comment: are you showing data of one row?

Comment: @eshirvana, no, this is 2 rows

Comment: Are your strings such as `"{steve,m,12.12.1995}"` contained in arrays, or is each row  text as well i.e `'{"{max,m,26.01.1980}","{sarah,f,18.04.1990}"}'`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 data type - text, so '{"{max,m,26.01.1980}","{sarah,f,18.04.1990}"}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object
                       ('birth_date', split_part(left(d.data, -1), ',', 3) :: date
                       ,'name', split_part(right(d.data, -1), ',', 1)
                       ,'gender', split_part(d.data, ',', 2)))
  FROM your_table AS t
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(t.your_text_column :: text[]) AS d(data)
 GROUP BY t
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c699f958574df578dd73c2cbd148820).

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
select Id
    , json_agg(json_build_object('name', split_part(jsondata, ',',1) , 'gender', split_part(jsondata, ',',2), 'birth_date', split_part(jsondata, ',' ,3))) json_info
from (
select id
,  replace(replace(json_array_elements(replace(replace(info,'{"','["'), '"}','"]')::json) #>> '{}','{',''),'}','') jsondata
from tablename
) t group by id
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ea5ce30e46cffa2f3e3d31cca059eca5)*